# Writing each sublist in a list of lists to a separate CSV

Tags: python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv, nested-lists, sublist

I have a list of lists containing a varying number of strings in each sublist:

```
tq_list = [['The mysterious diary records the voice.', 'Italy is my favorite country', 'I am happy to take your donation', 'Any amount will be greatly appreciated.'], ['I am counting my calories, yet I really want dessert.', 'Cats are good pets, for they are clean and are not noisy.'], ['We have a lot of rain in June.']]
```

I would like to create a new CSV file for each sublist. All I have so far is a way to output each sublist as a row in the same CSV file using the following code:

```
name_list = ["sublist1","sublist2","sublist3"]

with open("{}.csv".format(*name_list), "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in tq_list:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

This creates a single CSV file named 'sublist1.csv'.

---

I've toyed around with the following code:

```
name_list = ["sublist1","sublist2","sublist3"]

for row in tq_list:
    with open("{}.csv".format(*name_list), "w", newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Which also only outputs a single CSV file named 'sublist1.csv', but with only the values from the last sublist. I feel like this is a step in the right direction, but obviously not quite there yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the `*` in  `"{}.csv".format(*name_list)` in your code actually does is this: It unpacks the elements in `name_list` to be passed into the function (in this case `format`). That means that `format(*name_list)` is equivalent to `format("sublist1", "sublist2", "sublist3")`. Since there is only one `{}` in your string, all arguments to format except `"sublist1"` are essentially discarded.

You might want to do something like this:

```
for index, row in enumerate(tq_list):
    with open("{}.csv".format(name_list[index]), "w", newline="") as f:
        ...
```

`enumerate` returns a counting index along with each element that it iterates over so that you can keep track of how many elements there have already been. That way you can write into a different file each time. You could also use `zip`, another handy function that you can look up in the Python documentation.

Comment: That did the trick @quacodas, you rock! Separate question (feel free to not answer--you've already done your work), do you know how I could output the data transposed so that it's a single column instead of a single row?